# Stepper motor on raspberry pi callibration issues in python script

Tags: python, subprocess, raspberry-pi4, stepper

I am writing python a script in which I run a stepper motor over the GPIO pins of a raspberry pi and a leadshine driver. The script works by itself, and I have callibrated the stepper by making it run 50 times back and forth at different speeds using the stepper_run function by itself. And this works perfectly. My goal is to run a scanner timed with the stepper motor, using a subprocess call to a scanimage command.

The problem is that steps start to go slightly out of sync (say 100 steps on 12000) when I do other things in the script simultaneously, or right before/after I run the stepper. It is as if the python script isn't able to count its own pulses properly because it is busy doing something else?

Stepper motor definition:

```
def stepper_run(steps, speed, direction, delay):
    '''
    wrapper to run stepper
    '''
    steps = int(steps * (resolution/200))
    speed = (speed / (resolution/200))
    GPIO.output(ENA, GPIO.HIGH)
    print('ENA set to LOW - Controller Enabled')
    time.sleep(delay) # pause due to a possible change direction
    set_direction(direction)
    print('DIR set to LOW - Moving at ' + str(speed))
    print('Controller PUL being driven.')
    for x in range(steps): 
        GPIO.output(PUL, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(speed)
        GPIO.output(PUL, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(speed)
    GPIO.output(ENA, GPIO.LOW)
    print('ENA set to LOW - Controller Disabled')
    #time.sleep(.5) # pause for possible change direction
    return
```

Calling the stepper:

```
def canoscanlide400(currentposition):
    '''
    EDIT THIS DEFINITION TO MAKE THE SCANNER SEQUENCE
    '''
    #STEP1
    stepper_run(12190, 0.00059, True, 0.32)
    #STEP2
    stepper_run(11740, 0.000462, False, 0.32)
    #RETURN TO 0
    stepper_run(450, 0.000485, False, 0.32)
    return currentposition
```

The function that calls the scanner:

```
def scan(filename,device,fileformat,dpi,xsize,ysize):
    '''
    creates two files to hold the image and errors, respectively
    takes 6 arguments: filename, device, fileformat, resolution in dpi, x size and y size for the scanner
    '''
    with open(filename,'w+') as write_handle:
        with open('err.txt','a+') as ferr:
            out=subprocess.Popen(['scanimage', '-d', device, '--resolution='+dpi, '-x '+xsize, '-y '+ysize, '--format='+fileformat, '--mode=Color'],stdout=write_handle,stderr=ferr)
```

And finally this is how I call everything:

```
if (device and 'no scanners' not in device and 'some other error' not in device):
    print (device)
    time.sleep(5)
    for i in range (10):
        scan(filename,device,fileformat,dpi,xsize,ysize)
        currentposition = canoscanlide400(currentposition)
        print (currentposition)
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: if the raspberry is busy doing other things it might get out of sync, yes. Instead of sleeping for a fixed amount of time, you should calculate the elapsed time from the last call, and then calculate how much time left you have to sleep to get always the calls on time.

Comment: Thank you, yes that seems to be the case. The thing is, the subprocess.Popen call in the scan function is called asynchronous. After it is called it runs in the background. Within the python program the scan function takes less then a microsecond to call.

Comment: Yes, but those times accumulate over time. If you call something 1 microsecond late every time, after a while you will be executing things completely out of time. Even if the delay doesn't happen always, it's an accumulative error, since you will never sleep less than the fixed sleep time. If you plan to use the raspberry to do some work, it might be a good idea to externalize the control of the servo to a dedicated device, like an Arduino, which you can communicate via I2C or SPI

Comment: I see, yes that is probably a clean & reliable option. Meanwhile, I have actually managed to make it work (I think) by placing the stepper function and the scanner function in two separate python programs and calling both with a subprocess.Popen call... I am going to do some extensive testing, to see if it is still calibrated after a 100 times going back and forth. I would still like to know what the difference is between this and what I was doing earlier...